# Can I use meshlabserver on ubuntu 18.0 without graph interface

Tags: python, blender, cad, meshlab

I want to run `upsample.mlx` with `meshlabserver`.

```sh
meshlabserver -i ./model.obj -o ./model.xyz -s upsample.mlx
```

the content of upsample.mlx:

```
<!DOCTYPE FilterScript>
<FilterScript>
 <filter name="Poisson-disk Sampling">
  <Param type="RichInt" value="1000" name="SampleNum"/>
  <Param type="RichAbsPerc" value="0.011" min="0" name="Radius" max="1"/>
  <Param type="RichInt" value="20" name="MontecarloRate"/>
  <Param type="RichBool" value="false" name="ApproximateGeodesicDistance"/>
  <Param type="RichBool" value="false" name="Subsample"/>
  <Param type="RichBool" value="false" name="RefineFlag"/>
  <Param type="RichMesh" value="0" name="RefineMesh"/>
 </filter>
</FilterScript>
```

Can I install `meshlab` on Ubuntu 18.0 without graph interface and root permission？
I want remote process these `xx.obj` by `ssh`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. If you don't have root permissions, you will have to install meshlab into a directory of your user. This can be easy if qt5 is installed in the system, or a bit harder if not.

If you have another machine with same architecture, just copy meshlabserver and the libraries in the dist directory into your remote machine.